# Python, Google Calendar define a datezone

Tags: python, date, google-calendar-api

I am getting a list of my Google Calendar, but I want to restrict the collection in a datezone. I have a "now" like this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
```

And I want something like this :

```
end = the end of the day of now
```

But I don't know how to do it, have you any idea ?
I am using the list like this:

```
response = calendar.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now).execute()
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
end = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0,second=0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
```

`datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0,second=0)` gives you the **beginning** of this day, and then you add 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you ! But do you know how I told it to my response ? Because there is no timeMax, or I don't find it ...

Comment: Well, obviously, the same way you're doing it now - call `.isoformat()` on `end`, append `'Z'` and that's it: `response = calendar.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=end.isoformat()+'Z').execute()`; if that's not what you meant, you need to explain your goal more clearly.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was thinking I have to had timeMin and timeMax in response ! It's more clear now !